# Changing point color depending on value in real-time plotting with Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, time-series, real-time, bokeh

I am using Bokeh in an experiment to plot data in realtime and the library provides a convenient way to do that.

Here a snippet of my code to accomplish this tasks:

```
# do the imports 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

# here is simulated fake time series data
ts = pd.date_range("8:00", "10:00", freq="5S")
ts.name = 'timestamp'
ms = pd.Series(np.arange(0, len(ts)), index=ts)
ms.name = 'measurement'
data = pd.DataFrame(ms)
data['state'] = np.random.choice(3, len(ts))
data['observation'] = np.random.choice(2, len(ts))
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data.head()
```

This is how the data looks like.
[image: simulated data]

Next I have used the following snipped to push the data to the server in real time

```
output_server("observation")

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, x_axis_type="datetime")
x = np.array(data.head(2).timestamp, dtype=np.datetime64)
y = np.array(data.head(2).observation)
p.diamond_cross(x,y, size=30, fill_color=None, line_width=2,      name='observation')
show(p)

renderer = p.select(dict(name="observation"))[0]
ds = renderer.data_source

for mes in range(len(data)):

    x = np.append(x, np.datetime64(data.loc[mes].timestamp))
    y = np.append(y, np.int64(data.loc[mes].observation))
    ds.data["x"] = x
    ds.data["y"] = y

    ds._dirty = True
    cursession().store_objects(ds)
    time.sleep(.1)
```

This produces a very nice result, however I need to change the color of each data point conditioned on a value.

In this case, the condition is the state variable which takes three values -- 0, 1, and 2. So my data should be able to reflect that. 
I have spent hours trying to figure it out (admittedly I an very new to Bokeh) and any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: my data time series]

Answer (score 0):

When you push the data, you have to separate the groups by desired color, and then supply the corresponding colors as a palette.  There's a longer discussion with several variations at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1967, such as the simple boteh.charts dot example bryevdv posted on 28 Feb:

```
cat = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
xyvalues=dict(x=[1,4,5], y=[2,7,3], z=[3,4,5])
dots = Dot(
    xyvalues, cat=cat, title="Data", 
    ylabel='FP Rate', xlabel='Vendors',
    legend=False, palette=["red", "green", "blue"])
show(dots)
```

Please remember to read and follow the posting guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; I found this and several other potentially useful hits with my first search attempt, "Bokeh 'change color' plot".  If none of these solve your problem, you need to differentiate what you're doing from the answers already out there.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking through answers but none of them provide a hint on how to do it _real_time_. In your example you are manipulating Dot object where you can supply the palette. In my case the action is happening inside the loop where I am updating the data source object. It appear that data source object allows updating only data and not colors. Perhaps, I am still missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to figure it out. The key point is doing it real-time for each incoming data point.

Comment: Do you need to reclassify a point once it's drawn, or is it just that you need to add colors as you go?  Do you have an upper limit that would allow you to specify an artificially large palette, but use only the colors you need as you go along?  Can you afford to redraw with expanded data sets?

Comment: I need to just add the colors as I go. In the above example where I simulated data all data points are available upfront, however in real system that would not be the case.  Yes, I can afford the redraw the expanded dataset as I will be keeping a maximum window. Are you suggesting to create a new Dot object (or whatever plot object I have) for each incoming data point instead of updating the DataSource object? If that is the case, I will give that a try...thank you